# Python Manage.py Commands Not Recognized on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-manage.py, manage.py

Trying to run heroku run python manage.py migrate --remote [my app] and it is outputting a list of subcommands. Tried various other django commands with the same result, everything from 'shell' to some custom commands I invented.

heroku run python is working fine as well has other heroku commands (run ls). is there a problem with django apps at the moment? i haven't edited my heroku settings or done anything related to heroku (rolled back to much farther-back deploys and still broken, so isn't any recent code changes)

```
     Running python manage.py help migrate on tempotrader-staging... up, run.7740
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stream_django/enrich.py:3: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The utilities in django.db.models.loading are deprecated in favor of the new application loading system.
      from django.db.models.loading import get_model


    Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

    Available subcommands:

    [account]
        account_emailconfirmationmigration
        account_unsetmultipleprimaryemails

    [auth]
        changepassword
        createsuperuser

    [avatar]
        rebuild_avatars

    [charting]
        update_portfolios

    [django]
        check
        compilemessages
        createcachetable
        dbshell
        diffsettings
        dumpdata
        flush
        inspectdb
        loaddata
        makemessages
        makemigrations
        migrate
        runfcgi
        shell
        showmigrations
        sql
        sqlall
        sqlclear
        sqlcustom
        sqldropindexes
        sqlflush
        sqlindexes
        sqlmigrate
        sqlsequencereset

..... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku fixed it!

[Image of Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTPlJ.png)

[Full link here of status/incident report](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/868)